# GPIO code for reading rotary-encoder causing double readings

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to create some code, using the [periph.io GPIO libraries](https://godoc.org/periph.io/x/periph/conn/gpio), that will determine when a [rotary encoder](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/pec11.pdf) is turned and which direction it turned. Using a couple of tutorials I found online, I got the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "periph.io/x/periph/conn/gpio"
    "periph.io/x/periph/conn/gpio/gpioreg"
    "periph.io/x/periph/host"
)

func main() {
    if _, err := host.Init(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    aPin := gpioreg.ByName("23")
    defer aPin.Halt()

    bPin := gpioreg.ByName("24")
    defer bPin.Halt()

    if err := aPin.In(gpio.PullUp, gpio.BothEdges); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    re := NewRotaryEncoder(aPin, bPin)

    fmt.Println("reading...")

    for {
        a := re.Read()

        if a != none {
            spew.Dump(a)
        }
    }
}

type Action int

const (
    none             Action = 0
    clockwise        Action = 1
    counterClockwise Action = 2
)

type RotaryEncoder struct {
    aPin     gpio.PinIO
    bPin     gpio.PinIO
    last     gpio.Level
}

func NewRotaryEncoder(aPin gpio.PinIO, bPin gpio.PinIO) *RotaryEncoder {
    return &RotaryEncoder{
        aPin:     aPin,
        bPin:     bPin,
        last:     aPin.Read(),
    }
}

func (t *RotaryEncoder) Read() Action {
    t.aPin.WaitForEdge(-1)

    a := t.aPin.Read()

    defer func() {
        t.last = a
    }()

    if a == t.last {
        return none
    }

    if a == t.bPin.Read() {
        return counterClockwise
    } else {
        return clockwise
    }
}
```

I would expect a single output containing the direction of the rotation, every time the rotary encoder is turned one position, but instead, I'm getting two or more for every one position.

One "click" clockwise:

```
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
```

Two "clicks" clockwise:

```
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
```

One "click" clockwise, one "click" counterclockwise:

```
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 2
(main.Action) 2
```

OR

```
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 1
(main.Action) 2
(main.Action) 2
(main.Action) 2
```

I also attempted to use the [debounce wrapper](https://godoc.org/periph.io/x/periph/experimental/conn/gpio/gpioutil#Debounce), but it didn't seem to have any effect, regardless of what values I used.

Comment: You asked for "both edges". I have not looked at the library but it's pretty clear that this gets you two signals per click: one for "made contact", one for "released contact". (One is the rising edge as the digital signal goes from 0 to 1. One is the falling edge as it goes from 1 to 0. Depending on the switch, the open or closed position might read either way, although it's more common to have open=1, closed=0 since that works with open-collector TTL.)

Comment: @torek, I tried changing the [edge value](https://godoc.org/periph.io/x/periph/conn/gpio#Edge) to each of the available options (none, rising, falling, both), but it had no effect on the output.

Comment: It looks like the [debounce wrapper](https://godoc.org/periph.io/x/periph/experimental/conn/gpio/gpioutil#Debounce) is only a placeholder. I'll have to implement my own and report back the results.

Comment: I finally figured the issue out. The rotary encoder has four states, so detecting a rotation requires comparing the last four state transitions against a known correct set of transitions. Updated code [here](https://gist.github.com/toxygene/6ee54127aa1c133574da2f0d9bb0e8c2).

Comment: Ah, that's much more complicated than I would have guessed. That data sheet doesn't have one peep about how the rotation is encoded!